# Custom Errors not working with MVC4 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to follow the answer to this question:

[How to make custom error pages work in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

I have the following in my Web.Release.config:

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
</system.web>
```

I'm running in Release mode.  I've added the following controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    public ViewResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;  //you may want to set this to 200
        return View("NotFound");
    }
}
```

And views for the controller actions:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}
<div class="list-header clearfix">
    <span>Error</span>
</div>
<div class="list-sfs-holder">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        An unexpected error has occurred. 
    </div>
</div>
```

I can access these pages via manual navigation.  If I navigate to some bogus URL though, I get the standard yellow error page with ugly diagnostics info.

> ```
> The resource cannot be found.
> ```
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /ss

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you use HandleErrorAttribute in your Home controller?

Comment: @Andrey.Gubal yes, on all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If custom errors are enabled, as in your example, and you are using the `HandleErrorAttribute`, the ASP.NET MVC runtime looks for the `Error.chtml` file in the current requests folder or in the shared
views folder. In this setup, the `defaultRedirect (to GenericErrorPage.htm)` and status
code redirect URI ("~/Error/NotFound") **are ignored**.