# Prevent passing sensitive data when exception occurs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

What would be the best approach to prevent sensitive data being shown to the user when an `Exception` happens?

I've got an ASP.NET-MVC application which I recently updated to version 5 (not 5.1 yet).
And whenever an Exception happens, I see data which I rather not want the user to see.

Comment: You could set a custom action filter to catch unhandled exception and forward to a generic Error view that lets the user know an error has occurred. Decent write up on the subject here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422572/Exception-Handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options what you have in handling exception in ASP.Net MVC -

Option 1 - [Use CustomErrors in web.config with custom controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Option 2 - [Exception handling with HandleError Attribute](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc)

Option 3 - [Handle Application_Error globally](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/using-application_error-in-asp-net-mvcs-global-asax-to-handle-errors/)