# How to work with custom error pages in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, custom-error-pages

I tried to implement custom error handling in my demo MVC Application. But did not work out.
In my web.config I have the following entry for **CustomErrors** and **httpErrors**:

**I commented out the CustomErrors section in system.web**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework" requirePermission="false" />
  <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StudentContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication4;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication7-20160206005617;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication7-20160206005617.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules></system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers><modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="MvcApplication4.Context.StudentContext, MvcApplication4">
        <databaseInitializer type="MvcApplication4.Context.StudentEFInitializer, MvcApplication4" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
<elmah>
    <!--
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
    -->
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
  </elmah><location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <!-- 
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
      -->  
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <clear/>
        <!--<remove statusCode="404"/>
        <remove statusCode="500"/>-->
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="File" path="/Error/page404.html"/>
        <error statusCode="500" responseMode="File" path="/Error/page500.html"/>
      </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
  </location></configuration>
```

And in my FilterConfig.cs I have :

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
       filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

Here is my page400.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Page is not there dude !!</h1>
    Sorry about this.
</body>
</html>
```

under Error Folder. 
But still when I hit

```
http://localhost:49376/private/aaa
```

(aaa action method is not there ) instead of the custom error page it still gives me the traditional error page.

[image]

Here is my IIS Version screenshot :

[image]

**Update :**

I know the question seems a duplicate of an existing one. But still the answers given over there do not solve my problem .
I still do not get to see the custom 404 error page.

Comment: try `<customErrors mode="Off" `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make custom error pages work in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker .. did not help :( Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use webServer configuration:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error
        statusCode="404"
        path="/Error/page404.html"
        responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

And add this line to RegisterRoutes method on RouteConfig css:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Error/page404.html");
```

Comment: What versión of IIS Express is running on your machine? httpErrors doesn't work on IIS < 7.0. This [blog entry](https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging) can help you.

Comment: It is 7.5 . I am updating my question including all the screenshots . Please have a look.

Comment: I notice your HTML error page is a static file. Use responseMode="File" instead responseMode="ExecuteURL".

Comment: I tried the same . But still getting the same old 404 error page as attached . :( . Also I do not have any controller action method for the same. Should I need to have a controller's action method or are these settings enough only ?

Comment: I update my answer. You need to configure your routing configuration in ASP.NET MVC to ignore requests for static html pages. Note you need responseMode="ExecuteURL". Take a look of edited answer.

Comment: ...Something is very strange. For last 48 hours nothing is working , whatever I tried . Again no luck :(
Also you said " You need to configure your routing configuration in ASP.NET MVC to ignore requests for static html pages." ... but I need the custom error message to show .. right ? Why we need to ignore ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105833/discussion-between-balde-and-strugglingcoder).