# The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. - MVC to show 404 custom page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to do a custom 404 page.

I added an ErrorController as follows

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult PageNotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404; 
        return View();
    }
}
```

Added a View folder Error in the following hierarchy: 
Views > Error > PageNotFound.cshtml - which has my custom 404 message.

In web.config file in the `<system.web>` tag:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~Views/Error/PageNotFound"/>
</customErrors>
```

Comment: similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Answer (score 0):

I think the slash is missing after ~

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Views/Error/PageNotFound"/>
</customErrors>
```

Comment: Tried it however now this error occured Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Comment: If he's giving it the full path doesn't he also need the .cshtml or .htm or whatever file extension as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be redirecting to the controller action instead of the VIEW

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound"/>
</customErrors>
```