# How to reproduce the 504 time out error in the local host IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5, iis-express

So, in my ASP.net MVC 5 application one of the client gets redirected to `504 timeout error` while making a payment. I want to reproduce that error in localhost. I am running IIS Express. So, I am thinking if I can decrease the time out of my IIS to may be a second I will be able to reproduce the issue. So, is there any way I can change the time out of my IIS Express server. Please guide me. I opened running IIS Express of localhost and I found one file named `applicationhost.config`. I am not sure if I need to make any changes there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show custom error for "504 Gateway Timeout error"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595186/show-custom-error-for-504-gateway-timeout-error)

Comment: @EdSF: I have asked multiple question in single question in early days then I was told I should never do it. I think both question are different. I doubt this question is same as the one you have mentioned. Please reconsider.

Comment: Your latest comments in your original question points to it being "the same" or _related_ issues - about a timeout when making payment calls. Just modify your original question and provide details there so that those who can help have all the info/context (and remove this question). Best ~