# Exception in WebApplication, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I develop an ASP.NET MVC application. I would like to redirect user to error page if an error is occured. But if the error occured when the application is initializing I can not redirect user because "Response is not available in this context". Руку is my code:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //...

        throw new Exception("qwerty");
    }

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        // Here I have got an HttpException with message 
        // "Response is not available in this context"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute("Default");                           
    }
```

Is there way to redirect user to error page if the error occured when Application was initializing?

Comment: `if the error occured when Application was initializing` Do you mean 'prior to when it starts servicing web requests'?

Comment: @mjwills I mean "error occured `in Application_Start` method". English is not my native language and I can make mistakes in phrases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make custom error pages work in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: @mjwills when I wrap this line in a try/catch block Application doesn't work. in catch block I catch HttpException

Comment: So `try
{
HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute("Default");  
} catch {}` didn't work?

Comment: This would not work because if your application can't start then it can't respond to requests.  You could use IIS error pages possibly, depending on your specific situation.

Comment: Maybe because the application did not starts? So the routes are not defined...

Comment: @Pupkin Can you please update your post with your current code?