# asp.net mvc: Can we set http status code when route does not match

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

suppose this is my route which expect integer data for productid

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{productId}",
    new {controller="Product", action="Details"},
    new {productId = @"\d+" }
 );
```

so these route will work

```
/Product/3
/Product/8999
```

how could i redirect user to a preexisting view where i can show a friendly error message for this scenario?

one more things i like to know can we set status code when user will type `/Product/apple` and this route will not match any. so in this case i like to set `statusCode="404"`. if i can do it then below `customErrors` where i specified a view will be shown for 404 error. suggest me how to do it?

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/error.html">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/access-denied.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/page-not-found.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error.html" />
</customErrors>
```

please guide me if it is possible.

Comment: `/Product/apple` this request is current not matched by your route... 
Two things you can do...
1. remove productid regex parse and handle that in action
2. add new route that match string and call perticular action , in that action redirect to page you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current listed route is not matching with the request you said.

You should consider adding two routes like this.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                "Product",
                "Product/{productId}",
                new { controller = "Product", action = "Details" },
                new { productId = @"\d+" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                "ProductNotMatched", 
                "Product/{productId}", 
                new { controller = "Product", action = "NotFound" });
```

This will now call `NotFound` action when `/Product/apple` will get hit.

Next you can create an action and redirect it like this,

```
public ActionResult NotFound()
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
**// HERE you can redirect to specific html / razor view or static page as you wish**
        }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: NotFound() action is not taking any parameter for productid. did u miss your action to decorate for the param productid or is it intentional ?

Comment: this `return HttpNotFound();` set http status code 404 which redirect to my page page-not-found.aspx file ?

Comment: Thats intentional , `/Product/apple` , I suppose you didnt need `apple` in Notfound , if you need that , you can add string param there.

Comment: see my comment underneath that line , you need to add mvc view for that.

     ` <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />` this should work for mvc


https://stackoverflow.com/a/13905859/1018054

Comment: i read this write up http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages `ASP.NET issued a redirect to  /404.html?aspxerrorpath=/foo/bar`  specially see this line. we need to configure few more things in error page for 404 error.