# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Error Handle for - 404 Page not found

Tags: c#, iis, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5

For standard errors I use solution error handle (see code below), and also I tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4) (without effect)

**Global.asax.cs**

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();

        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        var routeData = new RouteData();

        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");

        if (httpException == null)
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
        else //It's an Http Exception, Let's handle it.
            switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
            {
                case 404:
                    // Page not found.
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "HttpError404");
                    break;
                case 500:
                    // Server error.
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "HttpError500");
                    break;

                // Here you can handle Views to other error codes.
                // I choose a General error template  
                default:
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "General");
                    break;
            }

        // Pass exception details to the target error View.
        routeData.Values.Add("error", exception);

        var request = Request;
        // Pass request details to the target request View.
        routeData.Values.Add("request", request);

        // Clear the error on server.
        Server.ClearError();

        // Avoid IIS7 getting in the middle
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
        IController errorController = new ErrorController();
        errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(
            new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

**ErrorController**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult HttpError404(string error, HttpRequest request)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Page not found (Error 404)";
        ViewBag.Description = error;
        return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
    }

    public ActionResult HttpError500(string error, HttpRequest request)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Internal server error (Error 500)";
        ViewBag.Description = error;
        return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
    }

    public ActionResult General(string error, HttpRequest request)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Internal server error";

        ViewBag.Description = error;
        return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
    }
}
```

**Error.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="exceptionmessage col-md-12 text-center">
        <div class="center-block">
            <img src="~/Content/i/404.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>

        <strong>@ViewBag.Message</strong>
        <span class="center-block small text-uppercase">@ViewBag.Main</span>


        <div class="center-block">@Html.ActionLink("Return to the Homepage", "Index", "Home", null, new {@class = "btn btn-primary"})</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a directory `Techs` where I have some XML files (for load data, something like local DB), and with this script in `web.config` I disable access to this folder and to download files from this folder (or when I write nonexist URL or file-like `www.test.com/afsdfgsdfg.pdf`), I got IIS message 404 Page not found without redirection to my custom error 404 page from error handler code below.

[image: Error Page]

```
  <system.web>    
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error redirect="~/Error/HttpError404" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>    
    <security xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="Techs" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Is there any way how handle all errors with 404 page not found (with same page and not two different)?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I add a new route for my `ErrorController` into `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Error",
                "{controller}/{action}/",
                new { controller = "Error", action = "HttpError404" });
```

after that I change `web.config` to:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/General">
    <error redirect="~/Error/HttpError404" statusCode="404" />
    <error redirect="~/Error/HttpError500" statusCode="500" />
</customErrors>

<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error
        statusCode="404"
        path="/Error/HttpError404"
        responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
```

But it still does not work, I got **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found** or **HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden** and similar messages, when I write for example:

- web.com/Techs/
- web.com/Techs/catalog.csv
- web.com/Techs.pdf -> redirect to the 404 page
- web.com/Home/c.pdf

Comment: Have you tried adding default route at last in route registration? Like if any route doesn't match then redirect to your 404 action

Comment: Hi, no from Error handle I do not have any Route in my RouteConfig.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution that WORKS

I do not add any new route to RouteConfig.cs, only edit file below. Controllers which I call method without a parameter, I have been treated differently. Global.asax.cs and ErrorController use same as above.

**Web.config**

```
<system.web>   
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/General">
      <error redirect="~/Error/HttpError404" statusCode="403" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/HttpError404" statusCode="404" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/HttpError500" statusCode="500" />
    </customErrors>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="403" />
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <remove statusCode="500" />
      <error
        statusCode="403"
        path="/Error/HttpError404"
        responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error
        statusCode="404"
        path="/Error/HttpError404"
        responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error
        statusCode="500"
        path="/Error/HttpError500"
        responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **web.config** add this line

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorHandler/Index">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorHandler/NotFound"/>
    </customErrors>
<system.web/>
```

edit:
That should cover all errors with that code...but I see that you already have that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder named like **Error** in the home directory, then create a html error page there with your own design.

In your web config, add this:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/404.html" />
</customErrors>
```

This would redirect to that *404.html* in the Error folder.

If you want to check for specific errors in the controller and redirect to the related error pages, you can create an **ErrorController** in the controller and the views for the different types of errors you want to check for in the *Error* views folder. eg:

```
    //In the ErrorController
    // GET: /Error/404 Bad request
    public ActionResult E404()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and in the controller if page is not found or id == null you can do something like:

```
if (id == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("E404", "Error");
}
```