# How to make MVC app use custom error page

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, error-handling, web-config

I have followed the answer on [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13905859/870565), but I am unable to get the app to redirect to the custom page upon encountering a 404 error.

When I visit `localhost:12345/error/NotFound` the error page is shown fine. So the controller to view link is all there.

I have setup an `<a>` tag with an invalid controller name to trigger the error page. Upon clicking the link i am taken to the browsers default error page and not my custom page.

I have tried adding `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` to `<system.webServer>`

I have tried commenting out `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` in FilterConfig.cs

I have tried adjusting `defaultRedirect` in my web.config file.

Nothing has worked for me, and I can not find any good straight forward documentation on this. And seems people have different approaches and different solutions working for them and not for others. Just makes me wonder...

### Here is my code:

**Web.Debug.config:**

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Error/Error">
      <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

---

**Error Controller:**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public PartialViewResult Error()
    {
        return PartialView("Error");
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public PartialViewResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return PartialView("Error");
    }
}
```

---

**Error.cshtml:**

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="list-header clearfix">
    <span>Error</span>
</div>

<div class="list-sfs-holder">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        An unexpected error has occurred. Please contact the system administrator.
    </div>
    @{
        if (Model != null && HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
        {
            <div>
                <p>
                    <b>Exception:</b> @Model.Exception.Message<br />
                    <b></b> @Model.ControllerName<br />
                    <b></b> @Model.ActionName
                </p>
                <div style="overflow: scroll">
                    <pre>
                        @Model.Exception.StackTrace
                    </pre>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

---

**Location of Error.cshtml:**

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there some other setting I have to handle? Is my redirect path supposed to point to error.cshtml or to its location?

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages) otherwise there is an MVC 5 guide [here](https://dzone.com/articles/make-custom-error-pages-work-in-aspnet-mvc-5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was set up perfect. Only issue was that **I was modifying Web.Debug.config instead of the Web.config file**. Once I moved my config changes to the parent Web.config file, my error pages started showing up.

Also, this: `defaultRedirect="~/Views/Error/Error"` did not work for me as a default redirect. Had to be a controller action instead of a path. Why path works for others, Im yet to know as this whole space is new to me.

Hope this helps someone someday.