# How to give error when entering incorrect username and password

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm setting up a project in C# ASP.NET MVC5 and I'm trying to give an error when you're entering incorrect username and password. So far I have tried with HandleError attribute without luck and now I'm trying with Membership.ValidateUser.

```
public ActionResult Login(User user)
        {
            using (CarsDBEntities db = new CarsDBEntities())
            {
                var usr = db.Users.Single(u => u.Email == user.Email && u.Password == user.Password);
                if (usr != null)
                {
                    Session["UserId"] = usr.UserId.ToString();
                    Session["Email"] = usr.Email.ToString();
                    Session["FirstName"] = usr.FirstName.ToString();
                    Session["LastName"] = usr.LastName.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
                }
                if (!Membership.ValidateUser(usr.Email, usr.Password))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password is incorrect");
                    return View(user);
                }
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Single()` throws an Exception if the sequence is empty, which will be the case for you if the email and password provided don't have a match. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netframework-4.8):

> InvalidOperationException
> No element satisfies the condition in predicate.
>
> -or-
>
> More than one element satisfies the condition in predicate.
>
> -or-
>
> The source sequence is empty.

`.SingleOrDefault()` will return a null in your case if the sequence is empty, letting you proceed to the null check on the next line. From [the other docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.8):

> Returns a single, specific element of a sequence, or a default value if that element is not found.

So try:

```
var usr = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == user.Email && u.Password == user.Password);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This worked but could you please tell me how I can throw a proper error instead of displaying where the error in the code is? If you know what I mean... btw why did my help/question get devoted did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Zagros - I haven't tried it (and I'm actually not all that familiar with MVC) but you could try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy,