# How to redirect to error page when http error 500.19 or hide config source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, http-redirect

I have Asp.net mvc project

it returns http error 500.19  when write wrong connection strings include '&'

How to hide this error or how to redirect error page

it shows all connectionstring from config how I prevent this

[image]

Comment: Try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make custom error pages work in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: If not, just add a try-catch... Your site shouldn't have unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Hi friends thank for for your answers but it is not handle an error.
it is like a build error. In web.config we get connection string. customers connection strings has '&' charackter it is not proper  for xml and it shows connectionstrings at web this is problem for us

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect an error page to another URL, you can follow this steps:

1. Open the Internet Services Manager.
2. In the Connections pane, expand the server name, expand Sites, and then navigate to the Web site or application that you want to configure custom error pages for.
3. In the Home pane, double-click Error Pages.
4. In the Actions pane, click Add...
5. In the Add Custom Error Page dialog box, under Status code, type the number of the HTTP status code for which you want to create a custom error message.
6. In the Response Action section, you can select Respond with a 302 redirect to redirect client browsers to a different URL that contains the custom error file.

[image]

Comment: I know that but this is not solution
I wnat to hide this or redirect an error page

Comment: I re-edited my answer, does this meet your requirements?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. This error throwed before project run

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Didn't your error appear after you posted it on iis?

Comment: Yes error appear after I posted it on iis but web config has connectionstring. Customer can change connection string because their connection string different and their connectionstring has & character so it shows an error when it browse I want to prevent this or show error page. İt is not redirect because web config has error ana when we browse, it shows connectionstring

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.